# form using jquery validate sends even if it fails and no post data sent to php

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, variables, post

Trying to have a form on site which is validated without the page refreshing so using jquery validate from here (http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Here is my form:

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" name="contact-form" >
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="control-group span4">
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Name (required)" id="name" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group span4">
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email Address (required)" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group span4">
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!-- end row-fluid -->
  <div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message (required)"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
  <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Send Message" />   
   </div>
 </form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass : "help-inline"
});

    $('#contact-form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {minlength: 2, required: true },
            email: {required: true, email: true },
            subject: {minlength: 2, required: true },
            message: {minlength: 2, required: true }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
               // do other stuff for a valid form
               $.post('process.php', $("#contact-form").serialize(), function(data) {
               $("#contact-form").hide();
               $('#results').html(data);
               });
          }
  });

}); // end document.ready
</script>
```

And this is the process.php:

```
<?php
// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form  
if (isset($_POST["save"]) || $_POST["save"] != "contact") { 
 // get the posted data  
$name = $_POST["name"];  
$email_address = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];   
$message = $_POST["message"]; 

// write the email content  
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";  
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n";
$email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message";  

// send the email  
mail ("myemailaddress@somewhere.com", "Contact form", $email_content); 
} 
print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_GET['name']."</b> and your     email is <b>".$_GET['email']."</b><br>";
?>
```

While the form appears to do validation, you can just override it by pushing the submit button. The behaviour should be that the fields have to be filled in before submit can work. Even if all fields are filled in, the form sends an email but it has no fields in it. It appears POST is not working in PHP or the javascript is not sending it to the process.php file. All this was based on this: http://developer-paradize.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/jquery-validation-validate-and-submit.html

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Do NOT use `isset` for $_POST variables. Use `!empty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {minlength: 2, required: true },
        email: {required: true, email: true },
        subject: {minlength: 2, required: true },
        message: {minlength: 2, required: true }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
        element
        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
           // do other stuff for a valid form
           var formData = $('#contact-form').serialize();
           $.post('process.php', {formData:formData}, function(data) {
           $("#contact-form").hide();
           $('#results').html(data);
           });
      }
});
```

Make these code changes (in the submitHandler). You will then have a single variable `formData` in **process.php** that you'll need to *parse_str* into an array. You can then use those array elements in process.php.

**process.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['formData'])) {
  // get the posted data
  parse_str($_POST['formData'], $arrPOST);
  $name = $arrPOST["name"];  
  $email_address = $arrPOST["email"];
  $subject = $arrPOST["subject"];   
  $message = $arrPOST["message"]; 
  // write the email content  
  $email_content = "Name: $name\n";  
  $email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n";
  $email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n";
  $email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message";  
  // send the email  
  mail ("myemailaddress@somewhere.com", "Contact form", $email_content); 
} 
print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$arrPOST['name']."</b> and your email is <b>".$arrPOST['email']."</b><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for answering. That has almost got it. The email is being sent now with the fields filled in. However, you can still click submit and the form sends even if the fields aren't filled in. I checked the console for errors but there aren't any. Is it possible there are javascript conflicts but they wouldn't show? Or is the validate plugin not really working?

Comment: Change this line:
`<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form">`

Comment: Thanks heaps, but not sure if it worked. Seemed to still allow the button to be clicked in Chrome if no fields filled in, but worked in IE. Cache issue? I cleared cache but Chrome still allows button to be clicked even if field not filled in. I've trimmed out all the other fields and left it with just asking for email - [here](http://www.buddycrm.com/new/index.html) to the form if you want to see its behaviour. It's the top email collection form field.

Comment: Validation is not working or it would have assigned `required` as a class to the individual inputs. You need to manually add `class="required"` to the `<input>` elements.

Comment: Thanks again. I added `type ="email"` too to make double sure and it's going now. There is obviously something big time wrong with that javascript validation plugin.